# Django REST || Python? Class attributes as a key-value pair array

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm currently doing the [Django REST Framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and I came across something when testing that confused me.

```
>>> snippet =Snippet(code='foo = "bar"\n')
>>> snippet.save()
>>> snippet = Snippet(code='print "hello, world"\n')
>>> snippet.save()
>>> serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
>>> serializer.data
>>> {'style': 'friendly', 'code': u'print "hello, world"\n', 'language': 'python', 'title': u'', 'linenos': False, 'pk': 2}
```

Specifically that last line. I don't define a `data` class or instance attribute.  The `SnippetSerializer` class is defined as the following:

```python
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES



class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new 'Snippet' instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing 'Snippet' instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
        instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
        instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
        instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I see that the `SnippetSerializer` class is relatives with `serializers.Serializer` (right?), but it doesn't seem there is a `data` attribute there either. It obviously works and allows me to access all of `SnippetSerializers` attributes as a key-value pair array. I just couldn't find documentation of this anywhere. Is `data` a reserved word in python? Is this something unique to Django REST? Or is there some inheritance that I'm not seeing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`data` is a property on the BaseSerializer class, from which Serializer inherits. See [the code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L200).

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find that. I just wanted to make sure python wasn't doing some fancy black magic.

Comment: Generally, Python follows the philosophy of "explicit is better than implicit", so black magic is frowned upon.